# cant draw a path using svg.draw.js

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I am making a very simple designing tool using [svg.js](https://web.archive.org/web/20171207151503/http://svgjs.com/) and [svg.draw.js](https://web.archive.org/web/20210301030531/https://svgjs.com/svg.draw.js/), in which user make a simple design using line, polylines, rectangles and free hand drawing as well. svg.draw.js is an extension of svg.js which allows to draw elements with your mouse.

Now lets take a look at very simple example. If we want to make any shape (such as polyline) using **svg.js**, we simply do like this:

```js
var draw = SVG('drawing').size(300, 300)
draw.polyline('0,0 100,50 50,100').fill('none').stroke({color:'blue'})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.3/svg.js"></script>
<div id="drawing">
</div>
```

To draw this polyline by mouse, i used svg.draw.js. Its very easy, we only have to include **draw()** function of this extension at the end of the above snippet. Also, we dont have to give any argument in the **draw.polyline()** function as well.

```
var draw = SVG('drawing').size(300, 300);
draw.polyline().fill('none').stroke({color:'blue'}).draw()
```

By including svg.draw.js library and draw() function at the end you will be able to create a polyline by mouse. For demo goto this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/EP2OxV5sCj0RmXk5VHve?p=preview).

**PROBLEM:** Now you see that by adding `draw()` we can create all the [svg elements](https://web.archive.org/web/20171210151008/http://svgjs.com/elements) by mouse clicks. By using same tactic, i want to do ***free hand drawing***. I am using **path** svg element for it but it doesnot work for me.

```
draw.path().stroke({color:'blue'}).draw()
```

The above line is giving this error:[image]

If svg.draw.js is supporting rectangles (`draw.rect()`), polylines(`draw.polyline()`) etc then why not paths? I want to create something like [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/f705fc55e6f26df29354), but this free hand drawing snippet is in **d3.js**
and i want to do it using svg.draw.js. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Paths are much more complicated than a polygon. You need to support acrs and beziere curves. It might be added in the future but dont count on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only draw lines, rectangle or circle etc. through mouse as you mentioned using this library. `svg.draw.js` **don't** have anything like `Draw.path()`.